# passing thrust::device_vector to a function by reference

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, thrust

I'm trying to pass `device_vector` of structures

```
struct point 
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
}
```

to a function in a following manner:

```
void print(thrust::device_vector<point> &points, unsigned int index)
{
    std::cout << points[index].y << points[index].y << std::endl;
}
```

myvector was initialized properly

```
print(myvector, 0);
```

I get following errors:

```
error: class "thrust::device_reference<point>" has no member "x"
error: class "thrust::device_reference<point>" has no member "y"
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: We don't know how thrust::device_reference is defined, so we can't answer the question. It looks obvious, however, that the class - though templated on point - doesn't directly expose x and y.

Comment: `index` parameter without type, should be `int index`?

Comment: @René Richter: Oops, copy-paste error. It should be unsigned int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `device_reference<T>` cannot expose members of `T`, but it can convert to `T`.

To implement `print`, make a temporary copy of each element by converting it to a temporary `temp`:

```
void print(thrust::device_vector<point> &points, unsigned int index)
{
    point temp = points[index];
    std::cout << temp.y << temp.y << std::endl;
}
```

Each time you invoke `print`, it causes a transfer from GPU to system memory to create the temporary.  If you need to print the entire collection of `points` at once, a more efficient method would copy the entire vector `points` en masse to a `host_vector` or `std::vector` (using `thrust::copy`) and then iterate through the collection as normal.

Answer (score 1):

From http://thrust.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.0/doc/html/structthrust_1_1device__reference.html :

device_reference acts as a reference to an object stored in device memory. device_reference is not intended to be used directly; rather, this type is the result of deferencing a device_ptr. Similarly, taking the address of a device_reference yields a device_ptr.

Maybe you need something like

```
(&points[index]).get()->x
```

instead of

```
points[index].x
```

It's a bit ugly, but CUDA needs a mechanism to transport data between RAM and GPU.