# Thrust vector of type uint2: "has no member x" compiler error?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have just started using the Thrust library. I am trying to make a vector of length 5 on the device. Her I am just setting the members of the first element `vec[0]`

```
  #include<thrust/device_vector.h>
  #include<iostream>
  .
  . 
  . 

  thrust::device_vector<uint2> vec(5);
  vec[0]=make_uint2(4,5);
  std::cout<<vec[0].x<<std::endl;
```

However for the above code I get the error

```
error: class "thrust::device_reference<uint2>" has no member "x"

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000020dc_00000000-4_test.cpp1.ii".
```

Where am I going wrong?  I thought that accessing a member of a native CUDA vector data type such as `uint2` with `.x` and `.y` was the correct way of doing .

Comment: Device vectors don't support direct access in the way you are trying. Use a separate assignment statement to a host variable and then print the host variable.

Comment: @talonmies It seems like "x" would still not be valid... fuller example?

Comment: @talonmies Thank you. It worked now. Looks like thrust can only print primitive data types like ints float and doubles from the device and notn any vector data types like `uint2`

Comment: @smilingbuddha Update for future :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing thrust::device_vector to a function by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624049/passing-thrustdevice-vector-to-a-function-by-reference)

Comment: @talonmies, your comment seemed like a good answer to me. I was wondering why you posted it as a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As talonmies notes in his comment, you can't directly access the members of elements owned by a `device_vector`, or any object wrapped with `device_reference`. However, I wanted to provide this answer to demonstrate an alternative approach to your problem.

Even though `device_reference` doesn't allow you to access the members of the wrapped object, it is compatible with `operator<<`. This code should work as expected:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

// provide an overload for operator<<(ostream, uint2)
// as one is not provided otherwise
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const uint2 &x)
{
  os << x.x << ", " << x.y;
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  thrust::device_vector<uint2> vec(5);
  vec[0] = make_uint2(4,5);
  std::cout << vec[0] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```